# How can I implictly convert one template class to another?

Tags: c++

This question is best illustrated by example

```
template <typename T>
struct expression {
};

template <typename T>
struct variable {
    operator expression<T>() const {
        return {};
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct member_variable {
    template <typename U>
    void operator=(const expression<U>&) {}
};

int main() {
    variable<int> a;
    member_variable<float> b;
    b=a;
}
```

As it stands, the assignment operator cannot be used because there are issues with deducing `U` (at least I believe that is what the errors are telling me). How can I make the code compile? I have also tried creating a converting constructor for `expression` that takes `variable` and that did not work either. I would like to avoid inheriting from `expression`, as it is a more heavy class in practice than the other two.

The `operator=`* is a stand in for other advanced usages, such as adding `operator*(expression<T>, expression<U>)` and being able to invoke them with `a*b`.

I've tried Clang trunk (8.0.0) and GCC trunk (9.0.0) with `-std=c++17`, and MSVC 15.9.3.

Clang message:

```
prog.cc:28:6: error: no viable overloaded '='
    b=a;
    ~^~
prog.cc:20:8: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'variable<int>' to 'const member_variable<float>' for 1st argument
struct member_variable {
       ^
prog.cc:20:8: note: candidate function (the implicit move assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'variable<int>' to 'member_variable<float>' for 1st argument
struct member_variable {
       ^
prog.cc:22:10: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'expression' against 'variable'
    void operator=(const expression<U>&) {}
         ^
1 error generated.
```

GCC message:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:28:7: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'member_variable<float>' and 'variable<int>')
   28 |     b=a;
      |       ^
prog.cc:22:10: note: candidate: 'template<class U> void member_variable<T>::operator=(const expression<U>&) [with U = U; T = float]'
   22 |     void operator=(const expression<U>&) {}
      |          ^~~~~~~~
prog.cc:22:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:28:7: note:   'variable<int>' is not derived from 'const expression<T>'
   28 |     b=a;
      |       ^
prog.cc:20:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr member_variable<float>& member_variable<float>::operator=(const member_variable<float>&)'
   20 | struct member_variable {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:28:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'variable<int>' to 'const member_variable<float>&'
   28 |     b=a;
      |       ^
prog.cc:20:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr member_variable<float>& member_variable<float>::operator=(member_variable<float>&&)'
   20 | struct member_variable {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:28:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'variable<int>' to 'member_variable<float>&&'
   28 |     b=a;
      |       ^
```

* As pointed out, usually `operator=` returns `T&`, however my use case for this class is (at least for right now) to not allow chaining.

Comment: What is the error message that you receive? What is your compiler? What is your operating system? Which version of C++ is this?

Comment: By the way, `member_variable::op=` should return `member_variable&` (though granted this is only a convention)

Comment: What is the error reported by the compiler?

Comment: Did You try to make `expression` a base class of `variable`?

Comment: The simplest way to make it compile is to add an overload for `operator=(const variable<T> &)` which is just a wrapper that invokes the existing `=` overload, but explicitly invoking the conversion operator.

Comment: I should provide some more detail, the other intended goal is to create multiple operators that use only `expression`, such as `operator*` but can be invoked with `a*b` (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of (or in addition to) implicit conversion I propose function for conversion:

```
template <typename T> struct expression {/**/};
template <typename T> struct variable {/**/};

template <typename T>
const expression<T>& as_expression(const expression<T>& e) { return e;}
template <typename T> expression<T> as_expression(const variable<T>&) {/**/}
```

And then use SFINAE on `as_expression`, something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct member_variable {
    template <typename U>
    auto operator=(const U& u)
    -> decltype(as_expression(u), void())
    {/*...*/}
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46b47b647750c7f9)

Comment: All these answers were informative, but this one answered the question that I had in mind.

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to invoke a function template instantiation that takes an `expression<U>` after deducing `U`. There is no `U` to deduce, though, because you're not passing an `expression<U>`. You're passing a `variable<int>`. It is true that `variable<int>` can be converted to `expression<int>`, but you're not triggering that. Deduction fails before conversion is attempted (because how could it be deduced from a totally different type?).

For a quick fix, `b=expression<int>(a)` [should solve it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee124e5a1f7c53e5). You could consider making a `decay()` function that does this for you, for what are effectively your own kind of lvalue-to-rvalue conversions! That's probably [about as terse](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0500f2be0d0949d1) as you can make it without further architectural changes.

Beyond that, I don't have a concrete solution for you, other than to say that you will need to rethink this class design according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to infer a two-step conversion, but:

- only a single conversion will be considered
- template matching inhibits implicit conversion.

You can make the given code work by introducing a temporary, either explicitly:

```
variable<int> a;
member_variable<float> b;
expression<int> c = a;
b = c;
```

or inline:

```
int main() {
    variable<int> a;
    member_variable<float> b;
    b = expression<int>(a);
}
```

Or, you might overload the `operator=` to perform the conversion:

```
template <typename U>
auto& operator=(const expression<U>&) {
    return *this;
}

template <typename U>
auto& operator=(const variable<U>& other) {
    return operator=(expression<U>(other));
}
```